# Marionette JS modules, Brunch JS and require JS project structure

Tags: requirejs, marionette, brunch

I am using BrunchJS to handle coffee script and assets compilation.
The project uses several Brunch plugins such as brunch-handlebar which requires the "commonjs"   wrapper to operate.

Extract from  my **config.coffee**

```
    modules:
        # We cant avoid require js wrapping since brunch modules use commonjs
        # Otherwise Marionnette JS offers its own modules loading strategy
        # loading mechanism
        wrapper: "commonjs"
        definition: "commonjs"
```

On the Marionette side I can have a simple application loading just fine.

**index.html**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = require('application');
    app.initialize()
  </script>
```

**application.coffee**

# Load handlebars block helpers
require 'lib/view_helper'

```
class Application extends Backbone.Marionette.Application
    initialize: =>

        @addInitializer((options) =>
            console.log "HELLO WORLD"
            AppLayout = require 'views/app_layout'
            @layout = new AppLayout()
            @layout.render()                
        )

        @start()

# module.exports is the object that's actually returned as the result of 
# a require call.
module.exports = new Application()
```

Starting from there how do I use Marionette JS modules ? I read about using modules with AMD here https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki/AMD-Modules-vs-Marionette's-Modules but I can not use the **define** keyword in my marionette module definition since "define" and "require" are not exposed. Brunch only uses it to load its plugins and my app source files.

A usual Marionette module looks like this:

```
MyApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

MyApp.module("Foo", function(){

  // module code goes here

});

MyApp.start();
```

In a separate file **moduleA.coffee** I tried to do:

```
MyApp = require 'application'

define ["MyApp", "Marionette"], (MyApp, Marionette) ->
  MyModule = MyApp.module("MyModule")

  MyModule.addInitializer ->
    console.log "HELLO FROM MODULE"

  MyModule
```

But **define**  is not defined.

I also tried to do:

```
MyApp = require 'application'

MyApp.module "ModuleA", (MyApp, ModuleA, Backbone, Marionette, $, _)  ->
    ModuleA.addInitializer ->
        console.log "HELLO FROM MODULE"
```

but then I need to require all my marionette modules ("moduleA") in application.coffee and ran into some circular dependency issues.

One of the solution I am thinking about is to disable BrunchJS commonjs wrapping and load handlebars from vendor folder instead of as a brunch plugin.

Comment: Have you set up you require.config?  I'm not sure about coffeeScript but I can give you a js example.

Comment: No I did not since I believe Brunch does it for us? I will give it a try.

Comment: It's possible it does, I'm not sure about Brunch either.  I use require, backbone marionette a lot and do not have this issue... so probably worth checking.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript example in case it helps!

I think the important bit is initiating you bootstrapper (main.js, in this example) via require.  It should be provided in a script tag attribute called 'data-main'.  Perhaps this is something Brunch does for you, I'm not sure.

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="js/main" src="js/libs/require.js')}"></script>
```

Then your main.js might look something like this.

```
/* global require, console */
require.config({

    baseUrl: 'js',

    paths: {
        'jquery': 'libs/jquery/jquery',
        'underscore': 'libs/underscore/underscore',
        'backbone': 'libs/backbone/backbone',
        'backbone.wreqr': 'libs/backbone.wreqr/lib/backbone.wreqr',
        'backbone.babysitter': 'libs/backbone.babysitter/lib/backbone.babysitter',
        'marionette': 'libs/marionette/lib/core/backbone.marionette'
        ...
    },

    shim: {
        'underscore':  {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: '_'
        },
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'backbone.wreqr': {
            deps: ['backbone', 'underscore'],
            exports: 'wreqr'
        },
        'backbone.babysitter': {
            deps: ['backbone', 'underscore'],
            exports: 'babysitter'
        },
        'marionette': {
            deps: ['backbone', 'backbone.wreqr', 'backbone.babysitter'],
            exports: 'Marionette'
        }
    }
});

// Start the main app logic.
require([
    'app'
],
function (App) {
    App.start();
});
```

Once this is all setup, you can initiate any resource prefixing the function with define, like this...

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'marionette'
],
function ($, _, Backbone, Marionette) {
    'use strict';

    // code goes here
});
```

Comment: But why would I need to shim marionette underscore and the rest when they are already exposed in my program.

Comment: As I said I'm not sure about Brunch and what it provides. However when using require.js, typically shim provides two main features.  1. dependency management, so require understands which order to load a requested resources. 2, to export your resource as a named global variable.